# ElasticSearch Script query is ignoring decimals from double value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-scripting

I'm using below query to fetch double value but it is ignoring decimals after dot.

```
POST gs011_tasks/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "version": true,
  "aggregations": {
   
        "DB_PLOTS": {
          "terms": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['area_count']", // this is double value:3.92922
              "lang": "painless"
            }
         
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
Area stored in elastic search is 3.925022
Expected value from above query is 3.925022
Actual value returned is 3
```

Can you please help me if we need to add any configuration?

Comment: Can you share the mapping of the `area_count` field?

Comment: Hi Val, actually the type is long ,but value stored is 3.925022. I think I need to change the type right ?

Comment: Yes absolutely, your type is wrong, probably because the first document you indexed had a long value (or simply 0) and that's why the mapping is long instead of double/float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that in your mapping `area_count` is of type `double` or `float`.

The reason you're seeing 3 in the response is probably because currently that field is of type `integer` or `long` because the first document you indexed had an `area_count` value that was an integer value (or simply 0).

Comment: Its working after changing the data type to double used below query to change                    PUT /indexName/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "area1": {
      "type": "double"
    },
     "area2": {
      "type": "double"
    }
  }
}